# Windows authentication for internal users and Login.aspx for external user

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Hi I am using the following code for internal users

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication  />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="xyz\abc" />   
        <allow roles="Users" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
     <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

Can anyone tell me how to direct it to Login.aspx for external users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MSDN article on mixing Forms and Windows security in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx) might help.

Comment: Hi can you explain me in details I have used the following code for internal users: <configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
   <allow users="XYZ\Domain Users" />
  </authorization>
  <identity impersonate="true" />
 </system.web>

Comment: @Valley, it's quite complicated and not something that was intended to work out of the box.  If you want details, you need to read the linked article, and study the accompanying source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
```

When the user is not authenticated it will redirect to Login.aspx